# Display images in listview from Arraylist of uri

Tags: android, listview

I am selecting multiple images from gallery,this gives me multiple uri of images that i add in `arraylist<Uri>.`
After getting all the `uri` of images in `arraylist` i want to view it in list view, I have created an custom adapter class that will be getting all the `uri` and on converting each `uri` to bitmap it will be set in `imageview` and this will list of images but it gives null exception.

This is the adapter class,
this class is present inside the activity

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ImageCount;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.imagelist_layout,null);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    try {

// getting null exception
       Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),mArrayUri.get(i));
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return view;
}
```

and on click of particular logo present in UI, i have set the adapter here.

```
 viewimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CustomAdapter customadapter = new CustomAdapter();
            images_listview.setAdapter(customadapter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: post your logcat. use ViewHolder Pattern.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.abc.ezkhata.EzKhataActivity$CustomAdapter.getView(EzKhataActivity.java:1331)

Comment: and use `ViewHolder pattern` for efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error at this Line.

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

change it to,

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

I Strongly recommend to use **ViewHolder Pattern** Only. Modify your class.

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ImageCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.imagelist_layout, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        try {

            // getting null exception
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),mArrayUri.get(i));
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView imageview;
    }

}
```

Comment: yes now it is working i was missing view from which it will set the image.

Comment: image count is 3 but still one image is gettingshown

Comment: sorry my mistake it works, the issue was with layout  when i added linear layout to my list view other images were visible.